# how to fix My text slider moving correctly in jquery in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel-5

I am running My text slider using jquery and css in Laravel. My problem is when it is moving there are two moving positions. that means one moving round running correctly and then next round text comming with different position. (little bit height positions to first ) how can fix this

this is My css

```
#slider {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.slider-container { 
    background:#FFF; 
    width:845px; 
    height:150px; 
    padding:20px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

}

#slider img { 
    width:200px; 
    height:125px; 
    margin:0px; 
    display:inline-block  
}

#slider li {
    width:300px;


}
```

blade view

```
<div class="slider-container">

    <ul id="slider">
    <li><a href="#"><p>Wealth Trust sign bond with </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Your capital has arise with </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>New Capital marcket </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>New Top Managers of </p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><p>Influence of </p></a></li>
</div>
</div>
```

I am using this tutorials to run My test slider http://wpandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/

can you give me solutions?

when I run images, then it is not this type problem....

in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/h4o9qsa4/ it is working correctly but why do not in My Laravel app?

Comment: Must be some css is affecting

Comment: can you guess the problem?

Comment: Try commenting some css which you have included.

Comment: For me, its like finding black cat in black room.

Comment: I did comment and check with css but not success any way will try more....